# What are machanics?

Tags: discussion, tags

Whilst looking at the [list of synonyms](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) I see that [machanics](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machanics) is a synonym of [mechanics](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mechanics).

Is *machanics* a thing, or a typo? If the latter then surely that tag should be deleted, as we shouldn't attempt to accommodate typos (common or otherwise) with synonyms.

Comment: It looks to me like it was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done and deleted machanics (nothing was tagged by it anyway)